# Type initialization exception in Stanford NLPCore

Tags: .net, exception, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the introductory F# example at the [Stanford.NLP.NET site](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET//samples/NER.Sample.html).  This is my code:

```
#I @"..\packages\Stanford.NLP.NER.3.7.0.1\lib"
#I @"..\packages\IKVM.8.1.5717.0\lib"
#r @"..\packages\IKVM.8.1.5717.0\lib\IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll"
#r @"..\packages\IKVM.8.1.5717.0\lib\IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll"
#r @"..\packages\Stanford.NLP.NER.3.7.0.1\lib\stanford-ner.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf
open System.Globalization

let classifiersDir =
    [|__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__; ".."; "data"; "NLPClassifiers"; "stanford-ner-2016-10-31"; "classifiers"|]

let classifier =
    CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(
        Array.concat [|classifiersDir; [|"english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"|]|] |> Path.Combine
    )

let str1 = "Good afternoon John Doe, how are you today?"
let str2 = "I go to Stanford University, which is in Caliornia."

printfn "%s" (classifier.classifyToString str1)
printfn "%s" (classifier.classifyToString str2)
```

I get the following exception when I try to run to code above:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'edu.stanford.nlp.util.Timing' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'java.util.ResourceBundle' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.<FindResources>d__0.MoveNext()
   at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.<FindDelegateResources>d__e.MoveNext()
   at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.<GetResources>d__14.MoveNext()
   at ikvm.runtime.EnumerationWrapper..ctor(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader _this, String name)
   at java.util.ServiceLoader.LazyIterator.hasNextService()
   at java.util.ServiceLoader.LazyIterator.hasNext()
   at java.util.ServiceLoader.1.hasNext()
   at java.util.ResourceBundle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(String baseName, Locale targetLocale, Control control, CallerID )
   at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.1.run()
   at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.1.run()
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Object , AccessControlContext , CallerID )
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction action, CallerID )
   at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getBundle(String baseName, Locale locale)
   at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getNumberFormatData(Locale locale)
   at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleResources.getDecimalFormatSymbolsData()
   at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Locale )
   at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols..ctor(Locale locale)
   at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(Locale locale)
   at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale locale)
   at java.text.DecimalFormat..ctor(String pattern)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Timing..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Timing..ctor()
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(String loadPath, Properties props)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(String loadPath, Properties props)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(String loadPath)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(String loadPath)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@() in C:\Users\amit-\Downloads\Noodle\NLPTests\NLPTests\Tests.fsx:line 42
Stopped due to error
```

It appears that the `Stanford NLP library` requires `Visual Studio 15.0.0`.  But I am running the latest version of the Community Edition, which is `version 15.3.3`.  Am I understanding the error correctly, or is there a different underlying cause for the exception?  (I am not even sure that I can download an older version of Visual Studio Community Edition.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I did some research, and the only reference to an exception that I can find is at [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET/issues/23).  I tried the recommendation of setting the `CultureInfo` to `en-US` explicitly.  But that has not solved the problem.

Comment: It looks like it can't load Timing. Have you tried "open edu.stanford.nlp.util"?

Comment: Unfortunately, `open edu.stanford.nlp.util` has not solved the problem.  The core problem appears to be this bit: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`.  I have searched for this error, and some people have suggested things like deleting the `.vs`.  But none of the suggestions has worked for me.